# Passing DataTable from View to new Controller method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, datatable

I'm trying to pass a DataTable from a view to a method in a Controller. When I try accessing the DataTable from the Controller, i get a NullReference exception.

The DataTable is filled in the view and I can confirm that by running this code in the view:

```
@{
    Debug.WriteLine("########DATATABLE COLUMNS########");
    foreach (DataColumn column in Model.Columns) {
        Debug.WriteLine(column.ToString());
    }
}
```

This returns the columns of the DataTable. When I try sending this DataTable to the Controller:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("expExcel", "Home", new {dt = Model} )">export to excel...</a>
```

The method in the controller:

```
public ActionResult expExcel(DataTable dt) {
    Debug.WriteLine("########DATATABLE COLUMNS########");
    foreach (DataColumn column in Model.Columns) {
        Debug.WriteLine(column.ToString());
    }
    //some more code...
}
```

Causes this error:

```
System.NullReferenceException
```

The error occurs when I try to acces the DataTable dt.

How do I pass a DataTable from a View to a new Controller method?

I have seen other posts about this problem, so far unanswered and that might be because the question is too specific in those cases. I tried generalizing more in this post.

Comment: You can't send datatable like this from view to action. I use a List<Model> for this purpuse and send data with a form.

Comment: @Janneman96 Can you show your GET action method for that View? It's weird to have DataTable as your model. It should be something like this http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rahul4_saxena/export-data-table-to-excel-in-Asp-Net-mvc-4/, use IEnumerable<Model> for the model.

Comment: @bounces Thanks, this looks like the solution I need, I am going to try it now.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same situation. I used the `TempData` for sending my `datatable` from the View to the Controller.
Hope this helps you.

View:

```
@{
    if (Model.LedgerTable.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        TempData["data"] = Model.LedgerTablelist(Model.LedgerTable);
        TempData["datatable"] = Model.LedgerTable; 

        <a href="@Url.Action("ExportToExcel", Model)" data-example-id="" class="btn btn-info" id="excelbtn"><i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Download</a>
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public FileContentResult ExportToExcel(LedgerDetails obj)
{
    //LedgerDetails obj = new Models.LedgerDetails();
    if (TempData["data"] != null)
    {
        List<LedgerData> liobj = new List<LedgerData>();
        liobj = (List<LedgerData>)TempData["data"];
    }
    if (TempData["datatable"] != null)
    {
        obj.LedgerTable = (DataTable)TempData["datatable"];
    }

    byte[] filecontent = Models.LedgerDetails.ExportExcel(obj.LedgerTable,obj);
    return File(filecontent, Models.LedgerDetails.ExcelContentType, "LedgerDetails.xlsx");
}
```

Comment: Please format your code.  The indenting seems to be all over the place